# Google Sheets: convert string to date

Tags: regex, date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have to following date string:

```
2019-05-07T19:00:00.000Z
```

I now want to convert date and time into 2 cells, but it still doesnt work with the date. I tried it with:

```
=LEFT(F2; FIND("T"; F2) - 1)
```

Which results in:

```
2019-05-07
```

But I can not convert this into a date like DD.MM.YYYY. If I type "2019-05-07" manually, I can convert it - but it is not convertable with the imported data. Why?

And I have the same problem with the time.

Comment: Maybe `=text(text(text(day(LEFT(C8,FIND("T",C8)-1)),"00") & "/" & text(month(LEFT(C8,FIND("T",C8)-1)),"00") &"/"& year(LEFT(C8,FIND("T",C8)-1)),"0000"),"dd.MM.yyyy")`?

Comment: awesome, this works! And how do I get the "19:00" in an other cell?

Comment: Maybe just `MID(F2, 12, 5)`? Or `=text(MID(F2, 12, 5), "hh:mm")`. I am not sure you actually need to FIND the `T` in the cell if the format is always the same. No need of regex either

Comment: Thank you so much, this was the solution: =MID(G2; 12; 5)

Comment: Is there any more thins that are unclear? Do you need any tweaks? Your example hints at the fact your strings are always in the same format, so using regex does not seem necessary, but please let know if you need to work with messier data - then something like `REGEXEXTRACT(F2, "^([0-9][0-9-]+)")` and `REGEXEXTRACT(F2, "T([0-9]+:[0-9]+)")` will come handy

Answer (score 2):

Google recently added [LET](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2023/01/google-sheets-powerful-functions-advanced-analysis.html) (and some other cool functions).

`LET` can help here, assuming `2019-05-07T19:00:00.000Z` is in `F2`:

```
=LET(
fecha, REGEXEXTRACT(F2, "(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)T.*"),
yyyy,  INDEX(fecha, 1, 1), 
mm,    INDEX(fecha, 1, 2),
dd,    INDEX(fecha, 1, 3),
DATE(yyyy, mm, dd))
```

Comment: Beautiful! Does `LET` work in ARRAYFORMULAS? I can't get this to work with F2:F...

Comment: `LET` is quite new, it's behaviour within arrayformula is not documented. And it does not look good for now. But check `BYROW` and `BYCOL`, I abuse those.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, albeit superficially, text functions (such as [LEFT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094079) and TEXT) return strings that Sheets does not attempt automatically to convert to a number that might then be presented in a Date format.

However, this can be forced with the [VALUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094220) function. Thus wrapping VALUE around what you tried, like so:

```
=value(LEFT(F2; FIND("T"; F2) - 1))
```

should, for your example, return `07.05.2019` when formatted with a custom format of

```
dd.mm.yyyy
```

Since tagged [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) you could apply:

```
=split(regexreplace(F3;"[A-Z]";" ");" ")
```

to replace both the `T` and the `Z` with spaces before splitting on spaces since the format looks likely to be consistent (eg always 24 characters) but a shorter version would be:

```
=split(left(F2;23);"T")
```

with application of suitable formatting for each of the date and the time.

Applying, as in a Comment,

```
=MID(G2; 12; 5)
```

has the potential disadvatage that [MID](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094129) is also a Text function (so not suitable for, for example, convenient formatting with AM/PM).

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a regex or even `FIND` if the format of the string values is always the same.

Get dates with

```
=text(text(text(day(LEFT(F2, 10)),"00") & "/" & text(month(LEFT(F2, 10)),"00") &"/"& year(LEFT(F2, 10)),"0000"),"dd.MM.yyyy")
```

(`text(..., "dd.MM.yyyy")` will do the conversion of a reformatted date string) and times with

```
=MID(F2, 12, 5)
```

See the Google Sheets screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
={TEXT(DATE(LEFT(A13, 4), MID(A13, 6, 2), MID(A13, 9, 2)), "dd.MM.yyyy"),
 REGEXEXTRACT(A13, "T(.*)\.")}
```

[image: 0]